# Adding polygons on points using Arcgis 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, editing, polygon-creation

I have a series (300+) of points and I would like to apply polygons over it. Cannot use the buffer tools as the polygons are not symmetrical but I basically need the same geometry for each one, repeating over the landscape. anyone have any ideas? I can write a model in modelbuilder to do it if I had to but why reinvent the wheel if there is a simple tool that does it already . the basic geometry of the polygons are shown below[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you're trying to achieve? I'm not sur I quite understand.

Comment: I have a series of points that represent research plots. I need to overlay the above polygon on the points to define the study area boundaries and compute a large series of metrics based on the spatial extent of the polygon. I cannot do this manually as I have over 300 plots to define

Comment: What metrics? You know that Buffer can either be a set value or the contents of a field.. but I am seeing rectangles, this is achievable in arcpy if you know the height, width and orientation of the rectangle but not (to my knowledge) in model builder.

Answer (score 1):

Create buffer of any radius around your points and run this expression, using field calculator on field Shape, parser - Python:

```
def makeRectangle(shp,H,W):
  hH=H/2;hW=W/2
  pcX=shp.centroid.X
  pcY=shp.centroid.Y
  LL=arcpy.Point(pcX-hW,pcY-hH)
  UL=arcpy.Point(pcX-hW,pcY+hH)
  UR=arcpy.Point(pcX+hW,pcY+hH)
  LR=arcpy.Point(pcX+hW,pcY-hH)
  rectangle=arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([LL,UL,UR,LR]))
  return rectangle
```

## ------------------------------------------------

```
makeRectangle( !Shape!,50,100)
```

Comment: Thanks felix, my python skills are sufficient to debug and cut and paste. writing from scratch gets me every time. great help!

Comment: Mark it as solved please if it worked